# Making a website banner slide take the whole width

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, templates

Is there a way to make the banner images that are displayed in the site below continuous? I mean, in the sample the current banner image is cut off on the left and in its place is part of the previous image.

I want the current image to take up the whole width of the banner.  Is that possible?

[Here's the Website Template](http://www.themes.evgenyfireform.com/provocateur/demo/index.html)

Here's what I think is the important part of the Slider:

CSS:

```
.wrapper ul {
    padding-left:490px
}

.anythingSlider {
    position:relative
}

.anythingSlider .wrapper {
    width:1920px;
    overflow:auto;
    height:405px
}

/* Width below is max for Opera */
.anythingSlider .wrapper ul {
    width:32700px;
    list-style:none
}

.anythingSlider .wrapper ul li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    width:auto;
    margin:0
}
```

JavaScript:

```
base.setCurrentPage = function(page, move) {
    // Set visual
    if (base.options.buildNavigation){
        base.$nav.find('.cur').removeClass('cur');
        captions.fadeIn(50);
        $(base.$navLinks[page - 1]).addClass('cur');
    };

    // Only change left if move does not equal false
    if (move !== false) base.$wrapper.scrollLeft(base.singleWidth * page);

        // Update local variable
        base.currentPage = page;
    };

    base.goForward = function(autoplay) {
        if(autoplay !== true) autoplay = false;
        base.gotoPage(base.currentPage + 1, autoplay);
        captions.fadeOut(200);
    };

    base.goBack = function() {
        base.gotoPage(base.currentPage - 1);
        captions.fadeOut(200);
    };
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slider-container">
    <div id="slider-holder">
        <div class="anythingSlider">
            <div class="wrapper">
               <ul>
                   <li>
                       <a href="#"><img src="images/content/banner1.png" alt="" /></a>

                       <p class="caption">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores</p>
                   </li>

                   <li>
                       <a href="#"><img src="images/content/banner2.gif" alt="" /></a>

                       <p class="caption">Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione</p>
                   </li>

                   <li>
                       <a href="#"><img src="images/content/banner3.gif" alt="" /></a>

                       <p class="caption">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam</p>
                   </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
       </div>

       <div id="bevel"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your image is just too small, but also the slideshow wrapper has a `490px` padding on the left. Try changing it to `100px` and see what it does. It's in `slider.css` first style. `#wrapper ul`

Comment: Yes.  That was partially the problem.  After taking away the padding the banner moved all the way to the left but now the right side has the same problem.

Comment: You need an image that would fill the whole space that you need. Otherwise add `right` or `left` margins to `.wrapper ul li`, it should separate the images by the amount you specify.

Comment: thanks for all the help.  I was able to figure it out.  The problem is now I don't remember how I fixed it. lol.

Comment: When I click on this [link](https://mobilemonkey.com/case-studies/mobilemonkey) I will see that after a couple of seconds a narrow strip/bar will appear at the bottom of the page. I have a website built with `Nunjucks` template (`html`, `javascript`, etc) that I would like to place a simple unobtrusive banner (narrow strip) on its homepage, to appear after a few second, where I can provide a little text or link or invitation to a survey. Is the answer to this post how I should do it, or is what I am looking for a totally different thing?